# Access specific attribute inside XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript, hta, xmldom

I'm trying to get the text inside specific attributes of this XML file.  For example the text inside the description, type, etc.

Currently I'm getting an error:

> Line: 23
>   Error: Object required: 'objNode.attributes.getNameItem(....)'

How can I access particular attributes of load XML file? description, details->serviceName, type

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>XML</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
        APPLICATIONNAME = "XPOS removal tool"
    />
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_onLoad
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmlDoc.Async = "False"
        xmlDoc.Load("programs1.xml")

        strQuery = "/steps/step"

        Set colNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes( strQuery )

        htmlString = "<table><tr><th>Description</th><th>Type</th><th>Status</th></tr>"

        For Each objNode in colNodes
            htmlString = htmlString & "<tr><td>"& objNode.attributes.getNamedItem("description").value &"</td><td>test</td></tr>"
            // htmlString = htmlString & "<tr><td>"& objNode.text &"</td><td>test</td></tr>"
        Next

        htmlString = htmlString & "</table>"

        DataArea.innerHTML = htmlString
    End Sub
</script>

<body>
<div id="DataArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

XML data:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<steps>
<step>
    <description>Description 1</description>
    <type>Type 5</type>
    <details>
      <runFolder>c:\windows</runFolder>
      <runFile>v3-x86.exe</runFile>
    </details>
  </step>
  <step>
    <description>Description 2</description>
    <type>Type 4</type>
    <details>
      <serviceName>COMRedirector</serviceName>
      <processName>COMRedirectorServ</processName>
    </details>
  </step>
  <step>
    <description>Description 3</description>
    <type>Type 3</type>
    <details>
      <serviceName>OSUpdate</serviceName>
      <processName>OSUpdateServ</processName>
    </details>
  </step>
</steps>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially this is what i wanted to do.

```
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.Async = "False"
    xmlDoc.Load("programs.xml")

    strQuery = "/steps/step"

    Set colNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes( strQuery )

    For Each objNode in colNodes
        strDescription = objNode.SelectSingleNode("description").text
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an attribute by `.GetAttribute(...)`, not `.Attributes.GetNamedItem(...)`. However, after unhiding and taking a look at your actual XML data: you're not looking for attributes in the first place. You want to select the text/value of XML nodes:

```vb
For Each objNode in xmlDoc.selectNodes("//description")
    htmlString = htmlString & "<tr><td>" & objNode.text & _
                 "</td><td>test</td></tr>"
Next
```